# smach sub State Machine userdata

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A related, simpler version of a previous post [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30160/propagate-userdata-smach)

Say I have a Top level Concurrence container, running

1. A ros topic monitor State
2. A sub State Machine, with its own states.

Can I pass updates received on the topic monitor to the sub SM states?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30492/smach-sub-state-machine-userdata/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 682 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, SMACH userdata is only loaded/unloaded from from states in a SMACH Concurrence when they begin and end, respectively.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1